# Yocto build parsing issue

Tags: yocto

Yocto build failed while parsing in Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Executed the following commands

```
#git clone -b sumo git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
#cd poky
#source oe-init-build-env
#bitbake-layers show-recipes
```

Got the [error](https://pastebin.com/JBcPH0Sm) while parsing. Can you guide to understand why this error occured and how to fix this.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are running `bitbake{-layers}` as root? Please note this is highly unrecommended if true.

Comment: I didn't run bitbake as root, I have pasted the complete log(https://pastebin.com/jNU27PGE) with id command. Tried to run bitbake-layers using -D option, but it is saying unrecognized option.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and `ls -l /bin/sh`.

Comment: Please find the output `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7` and `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 27 21:17 /bin/sh -> bash` . The output of `python -V` is `Python 2.7.15+`.

Comment: It seems the issue is with `"acl_2.2.52.bb"` file. I have removed "acl_2.2.52.bb" file and ran the `"bitbake-layers show-recipes"` command, then it didn't give any error. Not sure what is issue with the file "acl_2.2.52.bb". Any idea which variables will be checked in a .bb file when we ran the "bitbake-layers show-recipes" command.

Comment: Tried with the latest master branch `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git`, then `bitbake-layers show-recipes` executed successfully. After comparing the `acl_2.2.52.bb` file with latest master branch, the issue is with `subdir=${S}`. It was changed in `c7bd5c98dd02f032cc9eb53aa65e13ebecc59b9f` commit as `subdir=${BP}`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the latest master branch `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git`, then `bitbake-layers show-recipes` executed successfully. After comparing the `acl_2.2.52.bb` file with latest master branch, the issue is with `subdir=${S}`. It was changed in `c7bd5c98dd02f032cc9eb53aa65e13ebecc59b9f` commit as `subdir=${BP}`.